# Change document root to subfolder in cpanel

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, create-react-app

I have a React app created with Create React App. I need to sever the files from `/build/`. How to change to root to `/build`? I have already pushed the entire files ie src, public and this is with git. If I had known, id git only the build folder but that seems too late (deploybot, bitbucket etc).

Ive created a .htaccess file with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web.com/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.web.com/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !build/
RewriteRule (.*) /build/$1 [L]
```

But nothing works when I got to `/`. All that I see are the build folder, src etc

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser?

Comment: @anubhava I dont really want to show the url, is that ok? Let's say the url is `http://web.com/`, so I enter `http://web.com/`. I want that to server files from the build folder

Comment: Change first condition to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web\.com$ [NC,OR]` and retest. I didn't want to know your real URL.

Comment: @anubhava That worked? Mind explaining what went wrong in your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?web\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/build/
RewriteRule (.*) /build/$1 [L]
```

In your condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web.com/$ [NC,OR]
```

There is a trailing slash which is never part of `HTTP_HOST` variable and there is an an unescaped dot that may match any character.

You can also combine both conditions into one by making `www.` optional as in my answer.